# Texto máximo permitido respecto al contenedor y forzar ancho a la mitad de la pantalla

Tags: css, ionic, botón, ionic3

Buenas.
Estoy Usando Ionic 3.9.2.
Me gustaría saber 2 cosas..
Por un lado me gustaría **forzar el tamaño** de ancho de los botones independientemente de su contenido para que sean **todos iguales** y que estos ocupen obligatoriamente **hasta la mitad de la pantalla** (como los primeros 6 botones) para evitar esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por otro lado me gustaría saber cómo puedo poner que el texto de los botones sea el **máximo que permita el tamaño del botón** porque cuando visualizo la pantalla en otras resoluciones se desconfigura todo y queda fatal.

Este es el css que estoy utizando:

```
 .button{
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 12pt; 
    margin-bottom: -10px;

}
```

Saludos y gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No necesitas *casi* nada de `CSS` para conseguir lo que quieres...

Puedes usar [`Grid`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/grid/Grid/) y dividirlo en dos columnas (recuerda mucho al sistema grid de bootstrap).

Y luego puedes usar los atributos que [ofrece ionic](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/button/Button/) para los elementos de botones.

El único `CSS` que he usado es poner el `height` a una altura mínimo a los `button`:

<kbd>**[Ver ejemplo en Plunkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/tiWNwrgcBDrwMmx0IrYa/)**</kbd>

```
.........

<ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col col-6>
            <button ion-button block text-wrap>Primer boton</button>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col col-6>
            <button ion-button block text-wrap>segundo boton</button>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col col-6>
            <button ion-button block text-wrap>Texto Bastante Largo</button>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col col-6>
            <button ion-button block text-wrap>Texto Bastante Largo</button>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>

      ........

</ion-grid>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Es lo que buscaba!!!